# Zeppelin with Bigquery results in "SQL Execution returned an error!"

Tags: google-bigquery, interpreter, apache-zeppelin

I installed and configured Zeppelin as the document says.

1. I set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as environment variable in `conf/zeppelin-env.sh`

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/anderson/.ssh/gcp-credentials.json
```

2. Configured BigQuery interpreter by setting `zeppelin.bigquery.project_id`.

After these settings, I could run the following BigQuery SQL for public dataset wihtout any problem.

```
%bigquery
#standardSQL
SELECT departure_airport,count(case when departure_delay>0 then 1 else 0 end) as no_of_delays 
FROM `bigquery-samples.airline_ontime_data.flights`
group by departure_airport 
order by 2 desc 
limit 10
```

It works. But when I do connect to private dataset it does not work.

For example...

```
%bigquery
#standardSQL
SELECT id FROM `private_project_id.dataset.table` limit 1
```

It results in `SQL Execution returned an error!` ERROR!!

I tried to the same SQL in Python.
and..  it works.

```
%python
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()
# Perform a query.
QUERY = ('SELECT id FROM `private_project_id.dataset.bra_survey` limit 1')
query_job = client.query(QUERY)  # API request
rows = query_job.result()  # Waits for query to finish

for row in rows:
   print(row)
```

As experiment, I change the `gcp-credentials.json` file name to something like `gcp-credentials.json__backup` to test if the zeppelin BigQuery interpreter read the credentials actually. Surprisingly when I run the BigQuery query, there was no error message except for the same error message `SQL Execution returned an error!`.
I mean If the interpreter actually read the credential file, my expectation is it raise exception for something like `cannot find credentials` error.

How to solve this issue?
Am I the only one who suffer from this error?

Yeah. public dataset is working well.
The problem is to connect to the private dataset in BigQuery.
and in Python there was no such problem to retrieve data from private dataset.
(What I mean is the service account permission is not a problem. I use this service account in several applications with no problem)

Comment: Could you confirm if you are using Zeppelin locally or through Cloud Dataproc? If locally, could you share the documentation you’re using to set up Zeppelin (with GCP credentials)?

Comment: @SakshiGatyan I used this documentation 
https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/interpreter/bigquery.html 

I also read the 0.10.0 documentation 
https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.10.0/interpreter/bigquery.html

But the 0.10.0 documentation is broken. 
I mean there is a link in the documentation but the link is broken. 
the link text is "Zeppelin Google Cloud Storage"

Comment: This error is thrown because of `NullPointerException` ie. when an empty table is returned. Could you confirm if you’re querying the same table in both failed and successful attempts?

Answer (score 1):

This error is thrown as a result of `NullPointerException` ie in your case error seems to happen when an empty table is returned. Try querying a non-empty BigQuery table.